# Div is not moving + player movement

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is not working, my div is not moving, whats wrong?

```
function moveAnimate(x, y, element) {
   var leftX = document.getElementById(element).style.left;
   var topY = document.getElementById(element).style.top;

   leftX += x;
   topY += y;

$(element).animate({ 
    "top": topY, 
    "left": leftX,
}, 1000);    
}; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divv").on("click", function() {
        moveAnimate(400, 400, this);
    });
});
```

Here is normal div:

```
<div id="divv"></div>
```

And normal css:

```
#divv {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px; }
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code, why its not working?

And I have no idea how to do script to player movement, any ideas? I just want to set a player in the middle of some div and when I click somewhere player will go there. Can someone do that little script in easiest way and explain it to me?

Comment: Here is https://jsfiddle.net/9zsh4x9t/ if someone wants

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the cod now the div will be move to the position when you click with the mouse in the document:

```js
   var posX = 0;
   var posY = 0;
   var currentPositionX = 0;
   var currentPositionY = 0;

function moveAnimate(x, y, element) {
   var elementPosition = $(element).position();
   var leftX = elementPosition.left;
   var topY = elementPosition.top;

   leftX = x;
   topY = y;

$(element).animate({ 
    "top": topY, 
    "left": leftX,
}, 1000);    
}; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
        moveAnimate(e.pageX, e.pageY, "#divv");
    });
});
```

```css
#divv {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divv"></div>
```

Comment: Alright, can you explain why here is debbuger? Im a beginner

Comment: @Ven ek I forget it :) its working run the code snippet

Comment: Okay, but now, how to move that div sereval times in body element? i want to click anywhere and div will go there, on click

Comment: @Ven ek your code is create to detect the click event in the div not in the html body?? So the click event that you create is for the div and if you click the div another time it will move to the new position

Comment: answer me below please

Comment: @Ven ek I changed the code now the div will move to the position when you click with the mouse in the document